# Set data in columns using csv

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have three different arrays as give below

**Array 1**

```
array('column1 value1','column1 value2','column1 value3');
```

**Array 2**

```
array('column2 value1','column2 value2','column2 value3');
```

**Array 3**

```
array('column3 value1','column3 value2','column3 value3');
```

Now i want output in three columns with headings `First Value`, `Second Value`, `Third Value` in `CSV File` so my first array value should be in first value column second array value should be in second value column and so on.

I have Searched a lot but haven't find any solution.

Comment: Please post the code you've written so far...

Comment: _I have Searched a lot but haven't find any solution._  That means you also tried a few stuff. Let us see your code

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$array1 = array('column1 value1', 'column1 value2', 'column1 value3');

$array2 = array('column2 value1', 'column2 value2', 'column2 value3');

$array3 = array('column3 value1', 'column3 value2', 'column3 value3');

$headers = array('First Value', 'Second Value', 'Third Value');

$result = array_map(null, $array1, $array2, $array3);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($fp, $headers);
foreach ($result as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```

A nice solution that will work for you is to map all your values before you insert them using `array_map` and insert the headers separately.

The output of the above code is:

```
"First Value","Second Value","Third Value"
"column1 value1","column2 value1","column3 value1"
"column1 value2","column2 value2","column3 value2"
"column1 value3","column2 value3","column3 value3"
```

Comment: Hello @pr1nc3 suppose if i have 5 values for `$array1` and 4 for `$array2` and 3 for `$array1` how could it work?

Comment: There will be no effect in the array map it will just add an empty field like ,, in the csv

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that you just need to use fputcsv and loop over the data:

```
$filename = 'file.csv';
$headings = array( 'First Value', 'Second Value', 'Third Value' );
$array1 = array('column1 value1','column1 value2','column1 value3');
$array2 = array('column2 value1','column2 value2','column2 value3');
$array3 = array('column3 value1','column3 value2','column3 value3');

$fp = fopen( $filename , 'w');

fputcsv( $fp, $headings );
for($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
   fputcsv( $fp, [ $array1[$i], $array2[$i], $array3[$i] ] );
}

fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fputcsv` to create a csv file.

```
<?php 
$h = array( 'First Value', 'Second Value', 'Third Value' );
$a1 = array('column1 value1','column1 value2','column1 value3');
$a2 = array('column2 value1','column2 value2','column2 value3');
$a3 = array('column3 value1','column3 value2','column3 value3');
$f = fopen('filename.csv', 'w');

fputcsv($f, $h);
$i=0;
while($i<3)
{
    fputcsv( $f, [ $a1[$i], $a2[$i], $a3[$i] ] );
    $i++;

}
fclose($f);
?>
```